# For identical static_assert messages, should I rely on MACROS?

Tags: c++, c++11, macros, string-literals, static-assert

[static_assert](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_assert) has the following syntax, which states that a string literal is required.

> static_assert ( bool_constexpr , **string literal** );

---

Since an *instance* of a string CAN'T be observed at compile time, the following code is invalid:

```
const std::string ERROR_MESSAGE{"I assert that you CAN NOT do this."};
static_assert(/* boolean expression */ ,ERROR_MESSAGE);
```

---

I have static asserts all over my code, which say the same error message.
Since a string literal is required, would it be best to replace all the repetitive string literals with a MACRO, or is there a better way?

```
// Is this method ok? 
// Should I hand type them all instead?
// Is there a better way?

#define _ERROR_MESSAGE_ "danger"

static_assert(/* boolean expression 1*/ ,_ERROR_MESSAGE_);
//... code ...
static_assert(/* boolean expression 2*/ ,_ERROR_MESSAGE_);
//... code ...
static_assert(/* boolean expression 3*/ ,_ERROR_MESSAGE_);
```

Comment: As the assertion will be resolved at compile-time, I don't see the immediate benefit using a 'pretty' error message. If the assertion fails you know the point of failure anyway.

Comment: @pauluss86 yes, but if the boolean expression is complex, understanding why it was a failure may be difficult.

Comment: That is true although I always try to avoid complex conditions in an assert. Normally it's just an 'x && y' or 'x || y'. The error message I add is also quite short; I don't like multi-line expressions and adhere to the <80 characters\line convention. What I'd do for cases where a complex boolean expression is hard to avoid is split it into multiple asserts or add a multi-line comment above the assert that documents the rationale behind it.

Answer (score 0):

In C++ you should *not* define a constant as a macro. Define it as a constant. That's what constants are for.

Also, names beginning with underscore followed by uppercase letter, such as your `_ERROR_MESSAGE_`, are reserved to the implementation.

That said, ***yes***, it's good idea to use a macro for static asserts, both to ensure a correct string argument and to support compilers that possibly don't have `static_assert`, but this macro is not C style constant: it takes the expression as argument, and provides that expression as the string message.

Here is my current `<static_assert.h>`:

```
#pragma once
// Copyright (c) 2013 Alf P. Steinbach

// The "..." arguments permit template instantiations with "<" and ">".

#define CPPX_STATIC_ASSERT__IMPL( message_literal, ... ) \
    static_assert( __VA_ARGS__, "CPPX_STATIC_ASSERT: " message_literal  )

#define CPPX_STATIC_ASSERT( ... ) \
    CPPX_STATIC_ASSERT__IMPL( #__VA_ARGS__, __VA_ARGS__ )

// For arguments like std::integral_constant
#define CPPX_STATIC_ASSERT_YES( ... ) \
    CPPX_STATIC_ASSERT__IMPL( #__VA_ARGS__, __VA_ARGS__::value )
```

As you can see there are some subtleties involved even when the compiler does have `static_assert`.

Comment: I think you missed the point. They're asking if it's ok to replace the literal with a macro.

Comment: @jrok macros have a lot of potential danger, and so I wanted to check whether it was the best approach for code maintenance.

Comment: @jrok: questions about "OK" (your question) or "best" (the OP's literal question) cannot be reasonably answered without some clarification of what's meant. Otherwise it's all subjective, with different criterions of goodness. But comparing the OP's idea of defining the literal string as a macro, with this answer's idea of defining the whole invocation as a macro, you can see that the latter makes for **far less to write** each place one wants a static assert.

Comment: some compilers have unusal implementaion of static_assert, e. g. while your approach will work, OP's would not or will have a quirk or two. E. g. Microsoft preprocessor in some versions  wouldn't transfer unicode-encoded messages.